# Markov Chain Detailed Balance property

Tags: calculus, probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am having a hard time to understand the concept of the detailed balance; mostly because of the intermingled notation most of the resources use; which involves constant usage of random and state variables interchangeably.

Assuming a continuous state space, I wonder whether the following derivation of "detailed balance implies stationary distribution" true:

Let's assume we have the transition function $T(Z,Z') = p_{Z'\mid Z}(Z'\mid Z)$. $p_Z(Z=a)T(Z=a,Z'=b) = p_Z(Z=b)T(Z=b,Z'=a)$ as the result of detailed balance. Then I want to show that $p_Z(\cdot)$ is the stationary distribution of the Markov chain.

I set $$p_{Z'}(Z'=b) = \int  p_Z(Z)p_{Z'\mid Z}(Z'=b\mid Z)\,dZ = \int  p_Z(Z)T(Z,Z'=b) \, dZ$$

Then due to the detailed balance, we have $p_Z(Z)T(Z,Z'=b) = p_Z(Z=b)T(Z=b,Z')$ whenever the right side $Z'$ takes the same value as the left side $Z$. So, I replace the righthand side into integral and since it should be $Z'=Z$ and $dZ'/dZ=1$ I apply change of variables:

$$\int  p_Z(Z=b)T(Z=b,Z')\,dZ' = p_Z(Z=b) = p_{Z'}(Z'=b)$$

Since this is true for all $Z'$ $p_{Z}(\cdot)$ is the stationary distribution.

Are my reasoning and calculations correct here?

Comment: What is the nature of $p_Z$?  Is it a probability measure on the state space?  Or a probability "density" function?  If it is a "density" function, does it mean your state space is an Euclidean space?

Comment: Yes it is a density function and we can assume that our state space is the Euclidean space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is a comment, but I write it here because of the large formulas ...]

Your argument is correct, but your writing is not rigorous.  I strongly advise that you distinguish in your notation between a random variable and its possible values.  For example, I would write $T(Z=a,Z'=b)=p_{Z'|Z}(Z'=b\,|\,Z=a)$ for the conditional probability density function of $Z'$ given $Z$.

Then, the starting point would be
$$p_{Z'}(Z'=b) = \int_x  p_Z(Z=x)p_{Z'\mid Z}(Z'=b\mid Z=x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_x  p_Z(Z=x)T(Z=x,Z'=b) \, \mathrm{d}x\;.$$
By the detailed balance, this can be written as
$$\int_x p_{Z}(Z=b)T(Z=b,Z'=x)\,\mathrm{d}x = p_Z(Z=b)\int_x T(Z=b,Z'=x)\,\mathrm{d}x = p_Z(Z=b) \;.$$